# WP7 custom UserControl binding

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, user-controls

I create simple watermarked TextBox

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" Name="hint" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <TextBox Name="text" TextWrapping="Wrap" Opacity="0" LostFocus="TextLostFocus" GotFocus="TextGotFocus" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Defined property Hint

public String Hint { get { return hint.Text; } set { hint.Text = value; } }

But i can't use Data binding on Hiht property. Application localized on two languages and hint TextBox must display text on correct langauge.

Comment: Can you update your sample to show where you're trying to bind to Hint property?

Comment: <local:WatermarkedTextBox x:Name="loginTextBox" Hint="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizationManager}, Path=LocStrings.ENTER_LOGIN_HINT}"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your property (Hint) as a dependency property to have support for binding to it. See e.g. this online  [dependency property declaration creator tool](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/dependency_property_generator.htm).